# When mouse hovers over object make the object appear

Tags: css

Using the `a:hover {   }` function it is possible to (for example) highlight an element when your mouse points over it. Is it possible to make an element appear when the mouse hovers over it?

Comment: it is possible.

Comment: Yes it is see https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover as a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want exactly but you can try with `opacity`:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  The box appears
</div>
```